# Imagem rotacionando automaticamente

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Galera, estou com um probleminha no meu HTML/CSS...
Algumas imagens, geralmente de tamanho grande estão rotacionando sozinhas...

Segue abaixo um print para vocês entenderem melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que as duas primeiras imagens estão na posição correta, porém a terceira e a quarta estão viradas... sendo que quando faço o upload elas estão na posição correta...

Segue meu fonte:

```html
<div id="usr-image" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive small-spacer" style="width:100%; height:200px; background-image:url(foto-perfil/'.$fetch['id'].'-profile.jpg); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; cursor:pointer;">
  <p style="color:#FFF; font-size:14px; margin-top:165px;"><b>'.$nome[0].', '.$idade.'</b></p>
</div>
```

Fico no aguardo por favor, abs.

Comment: Cara, primeio sugiro que vc remova todo esse atributo style e faça essas alterações em um arquivo .css. Tente também inserir a foto usango a tag <img> em vez de inserir usando background.

Comment: Oi Felipe, ja utilizei a tag img.

Comment: Veja [esse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/oz2ovpmu/) de como você pode fazer fluir as imagens. E [neste exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/3evfLm7q/) eu destaquei para que você possa entender melhor como funciona.

Comment: Agora o problema que vc está tendo não é uma questão de CSS, é porque ela foi salva deitada, se vc abrir a imagem individualmente clicando com o botão direito do mouse em "abrir imagem em uma nova guia", você verá a situação real da imagem, isso aconteceu provavelmente porque a pessoa que enviou a imagem tinha ela salva deitada no celular.

Comment: Existem soluções que podem detectar rosto e posicionar sua imagem, [veja aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/php) ou [aqui neste exemplo](https://itnext.io/face-api-js-javascript-api-for-face-recognition-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-bcc2a6c4cf07).

Comment: [Aqui a lib no github](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js) e [outro exemplo](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs)

Comment: Ao fazer upload de uma imagem, também é possível criar uma pré-visualização da  imagem, onde ele rotacione manualmente como ele quer, só vai exigir um pouco mais de trabalho, mas vai resolver seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Abra a imagem de Ctrl + r ate fica na posição certa salve e use no seu html.

Já tive esse msm problema e assim resolveu

uma boa pratica seria colocar as imagens em <img src="" ...>
e o css em um arquivo separado.

Quanto mais simples o código melhor, assim você ou outra pessoa for dar manutenção futuramente não vai demorar.

Ex de como eu organizo meu html

```
insira o código aqui   <div class="gallery autoplay items-3 ">
            <div id="item-1" class="control-operator"></div>
            <div id="item-2" class="control-operator"></div>
            <div id="item-3" class="control-operator"></div>

            <figure class="item">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="itemCaroucel"><img class="" src="imagem/Escala-Hiper-Brinquedos-Postagem-1-1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>

                    <div class="itemCaroucel"><img src="imagem/Escala-Hiper-Brinquedos-Postagem-1-1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>

                    <div class="itemCaroucel"><img src="imagem/Escala-Hiper-Brinquedos-Postagem-1-1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item">
                <div class="flex">

                    <div class="itemCarousel"><img src="imagem/Escala-Hiper-Campanha-Material-Escolar-Postagem-1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="itemCaroucel"><img src="imagem/Escala-Hiper-Campanha-Material-Escolar-Postagem-1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="itemCaroucel"><img src="imagem/Escala-Hiper-Campanha-Material-Escolar-Postagem-1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>


                </div>
            </figure>

            <figure class="item">
                <h1>3</h1>
            </figure>
            <br><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="controls">
                <a href="#item-1" class="control-button">•</a>
                <a href="#item-2" class="control-button">•</a>
                <a href="#item-3" class="control-button">•</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tive esse problema, no pc a imagem fica normal, ao colocar no site ela rotaciona. Pra resolver isso, fiz o seguinte:

1. Abre a imagem em um editor de imagem e coloque ela, se estiver "virada", na posição certa.
2. Salve a imagem, mas não sobrescrevendo ela, salve com outro nome. Tente coloca-la novamente em seu html.